# silverlight/wp7: HTTPwebrequest BeginGetResponse lambda expression not working correctly

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am calling the HTTPwebrequest BeginGetResponse  within a loop with lambda expression (here the index is incremented each time in the loop).

Tried using both the below approaches, however when OnHTMLFetchComplete is called I only get the final index value and not the intermediate ones.

option1:

```
  HttpWebRequest itemHtmlRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(itemDetail.Links));
  itemHtmlRequest.BeginGetResponse(result => OnHTMLFetchComplete(result, index, itemHtmlRequest),null);
```

Option2:

```
  HttpWebRequest itemHtmlRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(itemDetail.Links));

  itemHtmlRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(
      result => OnHTMLFetchComplete(result, index, itemHtmlRequest)), null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the common problem of capturing a loop variable. The lambda expression captures the `index` *variable*, not its value. It's a simple fix though:

```
for (int index = 0; index < ...; index++)
{
    int indexCopy = index;
    Uri uri = ...;
    HttpWebRequest itemHtmlRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
    itemHtmlRequest.BeginGetResponse(
        result => OnHTMLFetchComplete(result, indexCopy, itemHtmlRequest),null);
}
```

Here you're capturing `indexCopy` instead of `index` - but whereas there's just *one* `index` variable, there's a new `indexCopy` variable on each iteration of the loop. The value of `index` changes over time, whereas the value of `indexCopy` doesn't, so you're okay.

Eric Lippert has a great pair of blog posts about this: [part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx); [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx).

(Note: there are *loads* of questions which have a similar answer. However, all the actual *questions* are different. I personally think it's worth answering each different *question*, to hopefully make it easier to find similar questions in the future.)

Comment: Seems to be the first time this has come up in WP7 context too. Some will search specifically on that tag for problems like this.

Comment: thanks a lot! wow such a easy fix and i spent hours trying to figure this out. Power of knowledge. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the whole code, my guess is that the outer loop iterations have already been completed before any of the async code has received any HTTP response.